# UIScrollView cover controllers on top

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a problem with an old project (Objective-C and No Auto layout).
I am trying to update some logic but I have a problem with a controller.

The structure of the controller is the same as the image attached

[image]

I have the problem that when I scroll up the tableView, the scrollView covers the button container view.

How can I solve this issue? I need that the scrollview does not cover that bar.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to have another `viewContainer` where you put on the `tableView` and the `Line Color`?

Basically you need to have something like that:

- `View`

  - `viewContainer` (Table View Container)

    - `tableView`
    - `Line Color`
  - `viewContainer` (Button View Container)

    - `button`